# How much CDR does Yasuo's Q get from bonus attack speed?

Tags: league-of-legends

> The cooldown and cast time of Steel Tempest is reduced based on Yasuo's bonus attack speed and unaffected by cooldown reduction.

Say I buy Blade of the Ruined King (+40% attack speed)

If Yasuo's Q is based on attack speed, how much CDR does Yasuo's Q get from that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Steel Tempest](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Yasuo) cooldown is reduced by 1% for every 1.72% bonus attack speed. Another easier way to think about it is for every 1% bonus attack speed he gets .58% cdr

> The cooldown of Steel Tempest is unaffected by cooldown reduction and is instead reduced by 1% for every 1.72% of his bonus attack speed. This is capped at 66% cooldown reduction with 114% bonus attack speed.
>   At max rank, the minimum cooldown is 1.33 seconds (1.4 attack speed).
>   Yasuo's 4% attack speed per level is factored into Steel Tempest's cooldown reduction and cast time reduction. At level 18, Yasuo has a total of 68% bonus attack speed from leveling alone which reduces Steel Tempest's cooldown by 40%. Steel Tempest's cooldown is effectively reduced by 2.3% per level.

So to answer your question 40% attack speed would get him 40/1.72(or 40*.58) = 23.25% bonus cdr for the ability